# Restart task (container) running in a ECS instance

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs

Need to restart a container(task) which is running in a ECS instance.

I've tried to restart the task using a lambda function(in CodePipeline).
stopTask is requires "task id".

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ECS.html#stopTask-property

```
function stopTask(clusterName, taskId) {

  console.info('Stop service: ' + clusterName + ':' + taskId);

  let params = {
    cluster: clusterName,
    task: taskId,

  };

  return new AWS.ECS().stopTask(params).promise();
}
```

Where as the "taskId" is not consistent. How can I get the taskId is based on "service name" and "cluster name" so that I can pass the value to stopTask

Lambda Runtime: Node.js 8.10

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using AWS JavaScript SDK [listTasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ECS.html#listTasks-property) operation?.

```
var params = {
  cluster: 'default',
  serviceName: 'my-service'
};
AWS.ECS().listTasks(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```